# Message driven bean in C#

Tags: c#, ibm-mq

Can any one suggest me code to write a message driven bean in C#.net to listen a MQ and process the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XMS will be pretty similar to JMS. This is a "hello, world" example of a message listener in C# using XMS. Please include the reference IBM.XMS.dll from your websphere mq installation.

On my windows installation, 32bit, it was

```
c:\Program Files\IBM\WebSphere MQ\bin\IBM.XMS.dll
```

This sample assumes a few hardcoded settings and have no error handling, but I think you get the idea.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using IBM.XMS;

namespace XMSTest
{
    class MyXmsApp
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            MyXmsApp app = new MyXmsApp();
            app.Setup();
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        public void Setup()
        {
            XMSFactoryFactory xff = XMSFactoryFactory.GetInstance(XMSC.CT_WMQ);
            IConnectionFactory cf = xff.CreateConnectionFactory();
            cf.SetStringProperty(XMSC.WMQ_HOST_NAME, "localhost");
            cf.SetIntProperty(XMSC.WMQ_PORT, 1414);
            cf.SetStringProperty(XMSC.WMQ_CHANNEL, "CLIENT");
            cf.SetIntProperty(XMSC.WMQ_CONNECTION_MODE, XMSC.WMQ_CM_CLIENT);
            cf.SetStringProperty(XMSC.WMQ_QUEUE_MANAGER, "QM_LOCAL");
            cf.SetIntProperty(XMSC.WMQ_BROKER_VERSION, XMSC.WMQ_BROKER_V1);

            IConnection conn = cf.CreateConnection();
            Console.WriteLine("connection created");
            ISession sess = conn.CreateSession(false, AcknowledgeMode.AutoAcknowledge);
            IDestination dest = sess.CreateQueue("queue://q");
            IMessageConsumer consumer = sess.CreateConsumer(dest);
            MessageListener ml = new MessageListener(OnMessage);
            consumer.MessageListener = ml;
            conn.Start();
            Console.WriteLine("Consumer started");
        }

        private void OnMessage(IMessage msg)
        {
            ITextMessage textMsg = (ITextMessage)msg;
            Console.Write("Got a message: ");
            Console.WriteLine(textMsg.Text);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Petter, it really help but I am confused a bit, will it read those message which are already put in queue and waiting for response.

Comment: I don't really follow you. It will read all messages. If there is a message with a reply queue set, and you know you need to reply somehow, that has to be handled manually in "OnMessage", so you would have to create a message, copy message id to correlation id and send it out. It should be rather straight forward

Answer (score 0):

MDB will be in Java. I am not aware if there is an application server that can handle MDB written in C#.

If your idea is to receive WebSphere MQ messages asynchronously using a C# application, then you can use [XMS .NET](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv7/v7r1/topic/com.ibm.mq.msc.doc/xms_cgetstd_intronet.html) which has a Message listener.