# How to get message constantly from remote IBM MQ

Tags: c#, windows-services, ibm-mq

I created a windows service that will connect to remote MQ and get the message as MQSTR format but after getting the message I didn't closed connection to remote MQ . My windows service will continuously check if data is available in remote MQ or not but after getting one message I need to restart my service to get the another message from remote MQ . Can anyone tell me what I need to do to get message constantly from remote MQ . Any clue or any link will do fine . Please Help

**My C# windows service code is like this :**

**Program.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.ServiceProcess;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace MQ_listner
{
    static class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            ServiceBase[] ServicesToRun;
            ServicesToRun = new ServiceBase[]
            {
                new Service1()
            };
            ServiceBase.Run(ServicesToRun);


        }
    }
}
```

**Service1.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.ServiceProcess;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;


namespace MQ_listner
{
    public partial class Service1 : ServiceBase
    {
        private MQReader MQReader;
        private string _serviceName = "MQ_Listener";
        private DateTime _TimeStart;
        private bool _run = true; 
        private Thread _thread;
        int WaitWhenStop = 0;
        private DateTime _TimeEnd;
        private TimeSpan _TimeDifference;
        private TimeSpan _TimeElasped = new TimeSpan(0);



        public Service1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                EventLog.WriteEntry(_serviceName + "was started at" + _TimeStart.ToString());
                _run = true;

                _thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(StartMQListenerService));
                _thread.IsBackground = true;
                _thread.Start();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                EventLog.WriteEntry(_serviceName + "was not started . Error Message : " + ex.ToString());
            }


        }

        protected override void OnStop()
        {
            _run = false;
            _thread.Join(WaitWhenStop);

            _TimeEnd = DateTime.Now;
            _TimeDifference = _TimeEnd.Subtract(_TimeStart); 
            _TimeElasped = _TimeElasped.Add(_TimeDifference);
            EventLog.WriteEntry(_serviceName + "was stopped at " + _TimeEnd.ToString() + "\r\n ran for total time :" + _TimeElasped.ToString());
        }


        // MQ connection service 

        public void StartMQListenerService()
        {
            try
            {
                if (_run)
                {
                    if (MQReader == null)
                    {
                        MQReader = new MQReader();
                        MQReader.InitializeConnections();
                        EventLog.WriteEntry(_serviceName + "MQ connection is established");
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.EventLog.WriteEntry(_serviceName, ex.ToString());
                System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startinfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
                startinfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
                startinfo.FileName = "NET";
                startinfo.Arguments = "stop" + this.ServiceName;
                Process.Start(startinfo);
            }
        }
    }
}


****MQReader.cs****

using System;
using IBM.WMQ;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml;
using System.Linq;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Configuration;

namespace MQ_listner
{
    internal class MQReader
    {
        public MQReader()
        {
        }
        public void InitializeConnections()
        {

            MQQueueManager queueManager;
            MQMessage queueMessage;
            MQGetMessageOptions queueGetMessageOptions;
            MQQueue queue;


            string QueueName;
            string QueueManagerName;
            string ChannelInfo;
            string channelName;
            string PortNumber;
            string transportType;
            string connectionName;

            QueueManagerName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["QueueManager"]; 
            QueueName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Queuename"];
            ChannelInfo = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ChannelInformation"];
            PortNumber = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Port"];
            char[] separator = { '/' };
            string[] ChannelParams;
            ChannelParams = ChannelInfo.Split(separator);
            channelName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Channel"];
            transportType = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TransportType"];
            connectionName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ConnectionName"];
            String strReturn = "";

            try
            {
                queueManager = new MQQueueManager(QueueManagerName,
                channelName, connectionName);
                strReturn = "Connected Successfully";

                queue = queueManager.AccessQueue(QueueName,
                MQC.MQOO_INPUT_AS_Q_DEF + MQC.MQOO_FAIL_IF_QUIESCING);
                queueMessage = new MQMessage();
                queueMessage.Format = MQC.MQFMT_STRING;
                queueGetMessageOptions = new MQGetMessageOptions();
                queue.Get(queueMessage, queueGetMessageOptions);
                strReturn = queueMessage.ReadString(queueMessage.MessageLength);
            }
            catch (MQException exp)
            {
                strReturn = "Exception: " + exp.Message;
            }

            string path1 = @"C:\documents\Example.txt";
            System.IO.File.WriteAllText(path1, strReturn);

        }
    }
}
```

Can anyone tell me what is wrong in my code? Do I need anything to add here to get message constantly from remote MQ . Please Help . Any link or clue will do fine .

**EDIT**

after certain amount of time I need to restart my service to fetch data from remote mq . Can you tell me why windows service needs to restart to fetch data . Any clue? any idea ?

Comment: There is no loop to get messages.

Comment: @Reniuz thanks for reply :) but can you tell me what I need to do cause I'm a bit confused how to get the message constantly from remote MQ. I'm starting my service then one message downloaded and for second message I have to restart my service again . cause service is running constantly but I can't get message constantly .

Comment: You need an Asynchronous Event to detect when you have receive data.  I looks like you have a form and I do not know why you need to use a thread if the form is already running.  Forms normally are processes so you do not need a second level of provided you use events to read the data.

Comment: On service start you just fetch one message. Just add loop to constantly fetch message. You know how to use threads( which you do not need here at all) so you should know how to write loop.

Comment: You can also look at XMS.NET which has a message consumer, you just register a onMessage method to be called for each message received.

Comment: An answer on this question has an example. 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11445728/message-driven-bean-in-c-sharp/11448628?s=3|29.5826#11448628

Comment: @Reniuz thanks again . I will add a loop to fetch message .

Comment: @JoshMc thanks for reply :) . thanks for the link and I will definitely look  into XMS.NET this for solving my issue .

Comment: @Reniuz can you tell me how can I add loop around this queueMessage = new MQMessage();
                queueMessage.Format = MQC.MQFMT_STRING;
                queueGetMessageOptions = new MQGetMessageOptions();
                queue.Get(queueMessage, queueGetMessageOptions);
                strReturn = queueMessage.ReadString(queueMessage.MessageLength);

Comment: @Reniuz how to check remote MQ is empty in C# . If mq is not empty then fetch all the message otherwise not . How to do this in C# ? any idea

Comment: If I recall correctly you will get an exception with certain exception message type when there is no messages in the queue.

Comment: Look for the MQRC_NO_MSG_AVAILABLE on search. Here is an example how someone fetching all data: https://coderanch.com/t/583361/application-servers/reading-mesage-MQ (second post will complete code)

Comment: @Reniuz thank you . From your clue I solved my problem

Comment: @JoshMc thank you for posting that link . XMS.NET is also another way to get the message from MQ

Comment: No problem. Now you can post your actual implementation as answer for future ;)

Comment: @Reniuz after sudden amount of time I need to restart my windows service to download files from remote mq . Can you tell me why? any clue?

Comment: Did something break? What error do you get? What logs/windows events shows? Maybe there is connection opened too long and was timed out. Maybe you got unhandled exception. I have no idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where is your queue close and queue manager disconnect?  If you connect and/or open something, you ***must*** make sure you close and disconnect from it.  I would strongly suggest you take an MQ programming course.  Or go to the [MQ Technical Conference](https://www.mqtechconference.com/) which has sessions on programming MQ.

I posted a fully functioning C# MQ program that retrieves all of the messages on a queue at [MQQueueManager message pooling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51534711/mqqueuemanager-message-pooling/51545804#51545804)

Here is an updated version of your MQReader class that should give you the right idea.  Note: I did not test it.  I leave that for you. :)

Also, you should be putting your connection information in a Hashtable and pass the Hashtable to the MQQueueManager class.

```
using System;
using IBM.WMQ;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml;
using System.Linq;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Configuration;

namespace MQ_listner
{
    internal class MQReader
    {
        private MQQueueManager qManager = null;
        private MQMessage      inQ = null;
        private bool           running = true;

        public MQReader()
        {
        }

        public bool InitQMgrAndQueue()
        {
            bool flag = true;
            Hashtable qMgrProp = new Hashtable();
            qMgrProp.Add(MQC.TRANSPORT_PROPERTY, MQC.TRANSPORT_MQSERIES_MANAGED);
            qMgrProp.Add(MQC.HOST_NAME_PROPERTY, ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ConnectionName"]);
            qMgrProp.Add(MQC.CHANNEL_PROPERTY, ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Channel"]);

            try
            {
               if (ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Port"] != null)
                  qMgrProp.Add(MQC.PORT_PROPERTY, System.Int32.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Port"]));
               else
                  qMgrProp.Add(MQC.PORT_PROPERTY, 1414);
            }
            catch (System.FormatException e)
            {
               qMgrProp.Add(MQC.PORT_PROPERTY, 1414);
            }

            if (ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["UserID"] != null)
               qMgrProp.Add(MQC.USER_ID_PROPERTY, ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["UserID"]);

            if (ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Password"] != null)
               qMgrProp.Add(MQC.PASSWORD_PROPERTY, ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Password"]);

            try
            {
                qManager = new MQQueueManager(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["QueueManager"],
                                              qMgrProp);
                System.Console.Out.WriteLine("Connected Successfully");

                inQ = qManager.AccessQueue(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Queuename"],
                                              MQC.MQOO_INPUT_AS_Q_DEF + MQC.MQOO_FAIL_IF_QUIESCING);
                System.Console.Out.WriteLine("Open queue Successfully");
            }
            catch (MQException exp)
            {
                System.Console.Out.WriteLine("MQException CC=" + mqex.CompletionCode + " : RC=" + mqex.ReasonCode);
                flag = false;
            }

            return flag;
        }

        public void LoopThruMessages()
        {
            MQGetMessageOptions gmo = new MQGetMessageOptions();
            gmo.Options |= MQC.MQGMO_WAIT | MQC.MQGMO_FAIL_IF_QUIESCING;
            gmo.WaitInterval = 2500;  // 2.5 seconds wait time or use MQC.MQEI_UNLIMITED to wait forever
            MQMessage msg = null;

            while (running)
            {
                try
                {
                   msg = new MQMessage();
                   inQ.Get(msg, gmo);
                   System.Console.Out.WriteLine("Message Data: " + msg.ReadString(msg.MessageLength));
                }
                catch (MQException mqex)
                {
                   if (mqex.Reason == MQC.MQRC_NO_MSG_AVAILABLE)
                   {
                      // no meesage - life is good - loop again
                   }
                   else
                   {
                      running = false;  // severe error - time to exit
                      System.Console.Out.WriteLine("MQException CC=" + mqex.CompletionCode + " : RC=" + mqex.ReasonCode);
                   }
                }
                catch (System.IO.IOException ioex)
                {
                   System.Console.Out.WriteLine("ioex=" + ioex);
                }
            }

            try
            {
               if (inQ != null)
               {
                  inQ.Close();
                  System.Console.Out.WriteLine("Closed queue");
               }
            }
            catch (MQException mqex)
            {
                System.Console.Out.WriteLine("MQException CC=" + mqex.CompletionCode + " : RC=" + mqex.ReasonCode);
            }

            try
            {
               if (qMgr != null)
               {
                  qMgr.Disconnect();
                  System.Console.Out.WriteLine("disconnected from queue manager");
               }
            }
            catch (MQException mqex)
            {
                System.Console.Out.WriteLine("MQException CC=" + mqex.CompletionCode + " : RC=" + mqex.ReasonCode);
            }
        }

        public void StopIt()
        {
            running = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Whenever you stop the service, make sure it calls the StopIt method in MQReader.

Comment: thank you :) for correcting my code . I closed MQ connection after getting message from MQ . But can you tell me why we need to use Hashtable for connection to remote mq

Comment: As I already said, MQEnvironment class is not thread safe and the way you were doing it does NOT allow for any type of security.  i.e. SSL/TLS or security exit.   Always, security FIRST, business logic second.

Comment: after sudden amount of time I need to restart my windows service to download files from remote mq . Can you tell me why? any clue? any idea . I closed connection from mq and I solved msg fetching from loop . why i do need to restart windows service again?

Comment: Well, if you close the queue or disconnect from the queue manager and you don't have code to reconnect after 1 minute or 2 then it sounds like you have a bad design.  There is no magic in MQ.  If you want it to reconnect without restarting the service then add code to do it.